# stripe custom payment element is not loading in react-stripe.js

Tags: stripe-payments

`I am trying to integrate stripe custom payment element with my current next.js project but not getting the custom UI .When trying to access that it is showing UI skeleton for some second then it is not rendering any UI and in network tab I am getting this get request error (
https://api.stripe.com/v1/payment_intents/pi_3MgonxSDFKrdPLJ70Xe0dquB?key=undefined & client_secret =pi_3MgonxSDFKrdPLJ70Xe0dquB_secret_pjhuuW2POWuC6UBiHAHhfFW04) it is showing like key is undefined. How can I fix this? thanks in advance

```
import { useState, useRef, useEffect } from "react";
import { CardElement, Elements, useStripe, useElements, PaymentElement, StripeProvider } from "@stripe/react-stripe-js";
import { loadStripe } from "@stripe/stripe-js";
import Stripe from "stripe";
// var stripe = new Stripe(process.env.STRIPE_PUBLISHABLE_KEY);

interface CheckoutFormProps {
    customerId: string;
    priceId: string;
}

export default function CheckoutForm(props: any): JSX.Element {
    console.log(props);
    const [error, setError] = useState(undefined);
    const [disabled, setDisabled] = useState(false);
    const stripe = useStripe();
    const elements = useElements();

    const paymentElementRef = useRef(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        if (props.client_secret) {
            const options = {
                clientSecret: props.client_secret,
                // Fully customizable with appearance API.
                appearance: {
                    /*...*/
                },
            };
      
                // const elements = stripe.elements(options);
                // console.log(elements);
                const paymentElement = elements?.create("payment", {
                    layout: {
                        type: "accordion",
                        defaultCollapsed: false,
                        radios: true,
                        spacedAccordionItems: false,
                    },
                });
                paymentElement?.mount(paymentElementRef.current);
            
        }
    }, [props]);


    return (
        <>
            <form >
                {/* <PaymentElement /> */}
                {/* <CardElement onChange={handleCardInputChange} /> */}
                <div ref={paymentElementRef} />
                <button disabled={!stripe && disabled} type="submit">
                    Pay Now
                </button>
            </form>
        </>
    );
}
```

Comment: The error means you are lacking the step of initializing Stripe with its PublishableKey. I am not familiar with Next.JS but look at Stripe Doc (React) for reference: https://stripe.com/docs/payments/accept-a-payment?platform=web&ui=elements

Answer (score 0):

```
yeah got answer for this.
before: I was using this code const stripePromise = loadStripe(`${process.env.STRIPE_PUBLISHABLE_KEY}`); using process.env.
after: const stripePromise = loadStripe("pk_test_51MgM6kSDFKrdPLJ7hBNfnyrKOx5GHvkEI1vBpySB80mjp5GgRDxISZP08AIkrjSKiD2PI3fT2IycMzuVdwHeKR7L00heXhBYXf");
directly providing publishable key
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).